# MongoDB with Mongoose: fast and short indexed document ids

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Employing MongoDB 4.2.5 and Mongoose in a MEAN environment, I am having two collections (books and authors) whereas many books can be associated to one author.

```
AuthorSchema = new Schema({
       //...
        books: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Book', required: false}] //option 1
        books: [{type: String, ref: 'Book', required: false}]                //option 2
    }, {collection: 'authors'});

BookSchema = new Schema({
        _id: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true},   //option 1
        _id: {type: String, required: true},                  //option 2
        shareID: {type: String, required: true},              //option 2 (e.g. dIxELcJsbLC)
    }, {collection: 'books'});
```

My goal is to create custom ObjectIDs for the books that are not as long as the native MongoDB ObjectID, but of course still unique - something like Youtube uses for each video (e.g. dIxELcJsbLC), which can also easily be shared online. Now, the problem is that I can not simply create my own unique string and cast it to an ObjectID as its structure has to adhere to certain structural rules (12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters) which pretty much just leaves me with option 2. That is, provide a plain custom created string UUID and declare it ._id of a book document.

As far as I know, working with a custom id in collections always performs worse than native ObjectIDs in the long run. How can I have both: ObjectIDs that work as efficient as can be while can also easily be shared online in a compact manner?

I was thinking about using native Object IDs internally (for relations across different schemas) and keep an additional shareID for sharing purposes (mydomain.com/book/dIxELcJsbLC-title), even though finding this book based on the shareID in a maybe some day huuuge database might take longer than referencing by native ObjectID. I hope you know what I mean. Another example for this approach probably is stackoverflow. When looking at this site’s url, you can see an integer value which clearly is some kind of identifier in the database but surely won’t be the primary/indexed value, am I right? So, they use a short identifier for external exposure as well as another identifier serving internal purposes (linking documents). Any thoughts on that matter? Thanks in advance for any experience shared.

Comment: You could re-encode the MongoDB ID from base 16 to a higher base, (e.g. base 36, which uses A-Z, 0-9 as digits or base 62 (A-Z, a-z, 0-9) if case-sensitivity is supported in the target context).

Answer (score 0):

There is no requirement that the `_id` field contain data of type ObjectId.  You can use whatever datatype you want, as long as it is indexed by a single entry, i.e. the value cannot be an array, and the `{_id:1}` index cannot be multi-key, objects as _id are allowed.

If you cast your custom value to an ObjectId, it becomes a 12 byte value anyway, so you lose any benefit of making it shorter.

As long as the `shareId` field is indexed, finding a document by its `shareID` field should not perform significantly differently than finding the document by its `_id`.

The only things special about `_id` are:
- it is indexed automatically
- uniqueness is enforced
- it cannot be updated on a document (you would have to delete and reinsert with a new _id)

Comment: So, you're saying that if I choose option 2 (that is keeping the native ObjectID for relations among documents AND introduce an additional but shorter sharingID - such as dIxELcJsbLC - which is also indexed) then I should be fine?

Comment: Absolutely, just build the appropriate index to support the way you want to query.